# Need a computer tool to find words with certain patterns of letters

Tags: software

I am trying to decipher some illegible writing by a nurse. For instance, I have a word where I am fairly certain the word starts with an *E*, ends with an *L* and contains a *T* somewhere in the middle. It could be *emotional* for instance, but I'm not sure.

Does anyone know of a computer tool out there where I can get lists of words that satisfy criteria such those in the example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try http://www.findtheword.info/.  If you [search for E*T*L](http://www.findtheword.info/Search.aspx?stype=words-matching-pattern&sword=E%2aT%2aL) it gives 663 possible matches for your word.  If you're reasonably sure of some more letters, you can narrow it down further.  For example if you're reasonably sure of the ending, [searching for E*TIONAL](http://www.findtheword.info/Search.aspx?stype=words-matching-pattern&sword=E%2aTIONAL) narrows it down to 33 possible words.

Comment: OneLook.com has a lookup feature with wildcards as well.

Comment: also morewords.com